# Android Tablet Application Development Basics

Tags: sdk, android

I'am developing my first android Tablet app. I want to develop the same app for smartphones also. What should be the minimum sdk version to develop an app for both? And how many layout folders i should have to support the app portrait & landscape modes on both the devices?

Comment: Why don't you get yourself a good book on Android programming?

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Comment: Go to android basics....do some work

Comment: @Alex by buyin good android programming book doesnot mean that we dont have a problem.. try to answer dnt give useless comments..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should be the minimum sdk version to develop an app for both?

Whatever you like. The minimum SDK version does not affect whether or not your app can run on a tablet. At this point, I recommend focusing on Android 2.1+, which would mean using 7 as your minSdkVersion, but that is up to you.

> And how many layout folders i should have to support the app portrait & landscape modes on both the devices?

As many as you need, and no more than that. In other words, it is impossible to answer this in the abstract.

Start by having everything in `res/layout/`. As you determine that you need other resource sets to make things work better (e.g., `res/layout-large-land/` for a tablet landscape activity layout), add them.